# How to mock method2 called from method1 from same class wtih Spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mocking, automated-tests, mockito

I have a spring-boot app with this architecture:

```
@Controller > @Service > @Component
```

Here's my Component:

```
@Component
public class myComponent {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;
    //com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

    @Autowired
    private Component2 component2;
    // some 3rd part REST service

    @Autowired
    private Component3 component3;
    //database access

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public List<SomePOJO> method1(String otherString) {
        String newOne = myString + otherString; //more logic here, but without components
        return this.method2(newOne);
    }

    public List<SomePojo> method2(String newOne){
        String one = component3.methodX(newOne); //access database with component3
        return component2.methodY(one); //more logic here, including component2 and mapper!
    }

}
```

Using `Mockito` I implement this at my test class:

```
@MockBean
public myComponent component;

@Before
public void before() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    List<POJO> someList = new ArrayList<>(); //list populated with some specific POJO's
    Mockito.when(component.method1("specificString")).
        thenReturn(someList);
}

@Test
public void recuperaDados() throws Exception  {
    String response = given().authentication().preemptive().oauth2("loginInfo")
            .get("myComponent_method1_path/" + "specificString1").asString();
    //this specificString1 leads to myComponent.method1("specificString"), satisfying Mockito 
}
```

And with this I successfully accomplished my tests. But when I use

```
Mockito.when(component.method2("specificString2")).thenReturn(someList);
```

And then

```
String response1 = given().authentication().preemptive().oauth2("loginInfo")
            .get("myComponent_method1_path/" + "specificString1").asString();
// this specificString1 leads to myComponent.method2("specificString2"), also satisfying Mockito
String response2 = component.method2("specificString2");
String response3 = component.method2("randomString");
```

response1 is `""`, response2 is `someList` correctly stringfied and response3 is `null`. `response2` and `response3` are expected. But I expected response1 to be same as `response2` or at least `null`. How can I correctly mock a method called by other inside same class and test calling the other?

**EDIT**

My test class extends this class:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public abstract class AbstractRestTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    protected Dsl dsl = Dsl.getInstance();

    @Before
    public void globalSetup() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.webAppContextSetup(wac);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the intention of your code to invoke method1 on the mock object expecting method2 to be called as a result? also could you show the full test for your second code example, and include any changes (if any) that you might have made to the @Before method?

Comment: @Dean yes, my intention is to call method1, follow the real implemented logic and receive mocked return from method2. The differences are on **EDIT**

Comment: You used `.get("myComponent_method1_path/" + "specificString")` in your second case. Shouldn't this be `specificString2`?

Comment: @ShanuGupta Sorry, it was a type to minimize my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mockito works by proxying the object that you wish to stub, and as such your implementation code will never be executed when calling methods on a mocked object unless specifically defined to do so. Consequently by calling method1 on the mock object, method2 will never be called as a result.

There is however a way to achieve your desired affect, by partial mocking. In your test in which you wish to test method2, you can indicate that the real method1 should be executed:

```
when(component.method1("specificString")).thenCallRealMethod();
```

It should be noted that the mockito [documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.18.3/org/mockito/Mockito.html#16) indicates that using partial mocks may be indicative of a code smell. In this cause the question is, does method2 really have to be public? If it is only public because you wished to mock it's implementation this is a mistake. With mocks you only wish to stub the public api of an object. Any private or helpers methods should be considered internal and ignored. The same goes for if you where testing that object, only the public methods should be tested, with helper methods tested indirectly.

You are right that the first result being an empty string instead of null is odd. I assume that it may have to do with something in code that has not be provided, e.g the controller or service.

Comment: My first result was an empty string because I had a json POJO wrapper at @Controller, and it was passing `""` when received null. I discovered that using `Mockito.when()` at method1(thenCallRealMethod, as you stated) and method2 made it work. My superior was quite interested after he discovered that documentation points out to some code smell, thanks for that part.